# Writing data into a csv file

Tags: java, excel, maven

I want to write data into a csv file, but that won't work. I already inserted the apache.poi dependency. Everytime when I try to run this, I only get the error message "Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel does not exist at main.WritingCSV.(WritingCSV.java:4)"

My code:

```
package main;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class WritingCSV {
    
    public void writing()
    {
        //Create blank workbook
      XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
      
      //Create a blank sheet
      XSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet( " Employee Info ");

      //Create row object
      XSSFRow row;

      //This data needs to be written (Object[])
      Map < String, Object[] > empinfo = new TreeMap < String, Object[] >();
      empinfo.put( "1", new Object[] {
         "EMP ID", "EMP NAME", "DESIGNATION" });
      

      //Iterate over data and write to sheet
      Set < String > keyid = empinfo.keySet();
      int rowid = 0;
      
      for (String key : keyid) {
         row = spreadsheet.createRow(rowid++);
         Object [] objectArr = empinfo.get(key);
         int cellid = 0;
         
         for (Object obj : objectArr){
            Cell cell = row.createCell(cellid++);
            cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
         }
      }
      //Write the workbook in file system
      FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
         new File("C:/poiexcel/Writesheet.xlsx"));
      
      workbook.write(out);
      out.close();
      System.out.println("Writesheet.xlsx written successfully");
    }
}
```

My pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>Migration</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Comment: Does maven even accept your pom.xml? The dependencies should be inside a `<dependencies>` tag. Also how are you running your application? That message indicates the dependency is not on the classpath when trying to run.

Comment: On a side note: you are _not_ writing CSV data but an _Excel_ file. For plain CSV (which is just text) I'd probably not use POI anyway.

Comment: Wow that was the error, now I feel stupid. But thanks a million

Comment: @Thomas what should I use instead?

Comment: Have a look at libraries like Apache Commons CSV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to wrap the `dependency` tag in `dependencies` tag, like this:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```